# Change DNS record but leave mail server the same

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

This is a screenshot of current DNS settings. If I want to change this domain to point to another web server but leave mail server the same, which records do I need to change?

[image: Screenshot of control panel]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the root A-record and the www record with the IP of your new webserver. Leave everything else.

Comment: what is the root record? Is it the one without www? What if I change only last one? Does it mean that iv-development.com will go to old server and www.iv-development.com to new server?

Comment: @ile: Yes, if you only change the last record that's what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to edit the last 2 to the new web server IP